# Problema de Auth2

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform

Estoy configurando el login mediante Google en mi aplicación hecha en laravel y para esto vi varias documentaciones al respecto, y todas eran mas o menos parecidas.

Probé con 3 configuraciones y en las 3 era el mismo error. 
La pagina es `xx` que es una app gratuita que quiero lanzar al mercado y me gustaría que la gente se registrara con google también. Alguien le ha aparecido este error?

Mi aplicación esta en Laravel 5.6, php 7.2, ubuntu 16, cloud compute de google. 
En Orígenes autorizados de JavaScript: http://localhost, lo mismo para URI de re direccionamiento autorizados

> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> The redirect URI in the request, , does not
>   match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the
>   authorized redirect URIs, visit:
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/1018359107925-kft140f29kvhpvffptkfe198qdttmkj0.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=1018359107925
>
> Learn more
>
> Request Details
>   client_id=1018359107925-kft140f29kvhpvffptkfe198qdttmkj0.apps.googleusercontent.com
>   redirect_uri=http://tundrainventarios.cl scope=openid profile email
>   response_type=code state=jSAyDaE5FExuJBp8pijXZnC7fjIQrDBh0oeK38mg
>   That’s all we know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error significa que no has autorizado a tus credenciales de Google para que acepten solicitudes de autenticación del la url **http://tundrainventarios.cl**. En esto caso, lo que tenés que hacer es ingresar a tu proyecto en la consola de desarrolladores yendo al link https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials y asegúrandote que estés en el proyecto correcto. Luego tenés que irte a la sección de las credenciales y actualizar los valores del **clientId** que estás usando. Tomá como ejemplo la imagen a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias ! 
En mi caso termino configurandolo de esta forma 
 http://tundrainventarios.cl/social/handle/google
Y ahi si ingreso

Answer (score 0):

No estas enviandole la direccion URI de autorizacion, tiene que ser una direccion de tu ptoyecto, en la imagen esta un ejemplo de como redireccionarla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(Adicional) en este articulo te muestro como puedes configurar el proyecto:

https://diegochavez-dc.medium.com/como-crear-credenciales-de-autorizaci%C3%B3n-de-clientes-oauth-para-enlazar-nuestra-app-con-informaci%C3%B3n-53397559c501

Comment: Las explicaciones deben ir _en la respuesta_, no como enlace externo. Si el enlace llega a caer, la respuesta se convertirá en inválida. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/340894)